# X times bigger than

Tags: grammar

How can I say:

X is 5 times bigger than Y (?)

Answer (score 4):

You can say 「X + **は** + Y + **の** + [５倍]{ごばい} + [大]{おお}きい。」.

You can also say 「XはYの５倍の大きさがある。」.