# comparing quantities

Tags: grammar

I have read [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23616/x-times-bigger-than) which explains how to say that something is n-times as big as something else. My sentence doesn't quite fit these patterns.

A fish has just been caught (no mention of size). The next sentence is:

> 岸辺を泳ぐ細長い魚の三倍はありそうなものだ。

So, I think it's supposed to be saying

> (the fish just caught) seems three times as large as the long, thin fish swimming along the river bank.

But there is no adjective in this sentence. So I don't really know if it's bigger, smaller, fatter, or whatever. Is there a clue in the grammar I'm missing that makes *bigger* the obvious choice? Or, must I just infer it from context (though, I don't think the context makes it particularly clear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say 「N倍{ばい} + はある/である/だ/です, etc.」 without explicitly describing the **quality** that is being compared between the two objects (as to "N times as ***what***"), it is always implied that the quality in topic is the ***size or amount in positive multiples***.

Thus, 「3倍{ばい} + はある/である/だ/です, etc.」 means "3 times as big/large/much (as the other one)".